# Machine Learning Dataset for Cyberbullying Tweets Detection

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, tweets

We are currently working on cyberbullying tweets detection using machine learning, we are unable to find a dataset for the same. So can someone please help us by sending the data set. We will continue our work depending on the data set.

We tried on specific sites and we created a dataset ourselves but that's doesn't seem to do the work. so please help us by sending the dataset for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Offensive Language Identification Dataset here:
https://sites.google.com/site/offensevalsharedtask/olid